How to handle shared units with GIT
I am new to the whole versioning/GIT world and have a bunch of units shared among several projects. I have started to commit my two biggest projects to GIT but I am unsure how to proceed with the units.
The units are outside the project folder, but (currently) only used in one project, though this might change. I have tried to add them to the project but they dont show in the online repo.
How do I setup GIT to have a versioning for those units? I dont see a way in the delphi GUI to commit them.

How are these units depending on each other? If someone doesn't need the source code of one unit for developing another, put them in different repositories.

The units are not depending on each other. Some have basic functions (A JSON helper class for instance) that are used everywhere, but mostly the cover some web APIs and are standalone.
How would I do this in the Delphi GUI?

In this type of problem, you have mostly 3 possibilities: git submodules, git subtree or a separated git repository where you build and publish packages (I don't know what is the type in Delphi) that are consumed by other projects.

With "add them to the project" do you then mean you copied them into the project folder? Or what exactly did you mean?

Just in case you are coming from SubVersion and were using svn:external before. The Git equivalent seems to be a Git Subtree. (I have no experience with this, though, I just read about it the first time.)

@Kim No they are still in their folders, but I added them to the project, making the visible in the project files. I used the project option "add files"

You should not work just with the CVS functionality the Delphi IDE is providing because it is very incomplete in my opinion. Better use an external tool like the Git command line or a tool extending Windows Explorer context menu like e.g. TortoiseGit

@DelphiCoder VCS not CVS  (I was wondering why you started talking about CVS...)

@Philippe of course this means "code versioning system" ;-)

Is there a reason you're not taking a Git tutorial instead of asking us to provide that tutorial? SO is not intended to be used as a replacement for doing your own research and making an effort to solve the problem yourself first, and taking a tutorial is part of that research and effort. You could also search here for existing Git posts, like Git for-beginners - the definitive practical guide
